# Como ativar o "explicit_defaults_for_timestamp"?

Tags: mysql

Instalei o MySQL Server 5.6. Quando tento ligar o servidor do MySQL executando o mysqld.exe, recebo a seguinte mensagem:

```
[Warning] TIMESTAMP with implicit DEFAULT value is deprecated. Please use --explicit_defaults_for_timestamp server option (see documentation for more details).
```

De fato, a solução está na documentação, mas não encontrei uma maneira de como pô-la em prática. Alguns dizem para colocar `explicit_defaults_for_timestamp = true` no arquivo `my.ini`, outros dizem para colocar no arquivo `my.cnf`, mas não há nenhum desses arquivos aqui. Também me disseram que é possível resolver isso colocando o MySQL como serviço do Windows, mas não o vejo na lista de serviços.

Como eu posso consertar esse problema e iniciar o servidor normalmente?

---

Criei o arquivo `my.ini` manualmente, o erro sumiu, porém outro apareceu, duas vezes:

```
2014-08-28 19:27:45 1292 [Warning] Can't create test file C:\Program Files\MySQL\MySQL Server 5.6\data\Patrick.lower-test
2014-08-28 19:27:45 1292 [Warning] Can't create test file C:\Program Files\MySQL\MySQL Server 5.6\data\Patrick.lower-test
```

Isso quando tento executar o `mysqld.exe`, quando tento executar o `mysql.exe` aparece o seguinte:

```
ERROR 2003 <HY000>: Can't connect to MySQL server on 'localhost' <10061>
```

---

Hoje tentei iniciar o MySQL pelo NetBeans 8.0.1 e apareceu isto:

```
2014-09-22 23:32:55 2580 [Warning] Can't create test file C:\Program Files\MySQL\MySQL Server 5.6\data\Patrick.lower-test
2014-09-22 23:32:58 2580 [Warning] Can't create test file C:\Program Files\MySQL\MySQL Server 5.6\data\Patrick.lower-test
2014-09-22 23:32:58 2580 [Note] Plugin 'FEDERATED' is disabled.
2014-09-22 23:33:02 2580 [Note] InnoDB: Using atomics to ref count buffer pool pages
2014-09-22 23:33:02 2580 [Note] InnoDB: The InnoDB memory heap is disabled
2014-09-22 23:33:02 2580 [Note] InnoDB: Mutexes and rw_locks use Windows interlocked functions
2014-09-22 23:33:02 2580 [Note] InnoDB: Memory barrier is not used
2014-09-22 23:33:02 2580 [Note] InnoDB: Compressed tables use zlib 1.2.3
2014-09-22 23:33:02 2580 [Note] InnoDB: Not using CPU crc32 instructions
2014-09-22 23:33:03 2580 [Note] InnoDB: Initializing buffer pool, size = 128.0M
2014-09-22 23:33:04 2580 [Note] InnoDB: Completed initialization of buffer pool
2014-09-22 23:33:04 2580 [ERROR] InnoDB: .\ibdata1 can't be opened in read-write mode
2014-09-22 23:33:04 2580 [ERROR] InnoDB: The system tablespace must be writable!
2014-09-22 23:33:04 2580 [ERROR] Plugin 'InnoDB' init function returned error.
2014-09-22 23:33:04 2580 [ERROR] Plugin 'InnoDB' registration as a STORAGE ENGINE failed.
2014-09-22 23:33:04 2580 [ERROR] Unknown/unsupported storage engine: InnoDB
2014-09-22 23:33:04 2580 [ERROR] Aborting

2014-09-22 23:33:05 2580 [Note] Binlog end
2014-09-22 23:33:05 2580 [Note] Shutting down plugin 'partition'
2014-09-22 23:33:05 2580 [Note] Shutting down plugin 'PERFORMANCE_SCHEMA'
2014-09-22 23:33:05 2580 [Note] Shutting down plugin 'INNODB_SYS_DATAFILES'
2014-09-22 23:33:05 2580 [Note] Shutting down plugin 'INNODB_SYS_TABLESPACES'
2014-09-22 23:33:05 2580 [Note] Shutting down plugin 'INNODB_SYS_FOREIGN_COLS'
2014-09-22 23:33:05 2580 [Note] Shutting down plugin 'INNODB_SYS_FOREIGN'
2014-09-22 23:33:06 2580 [Note] Shutting down plugin 'INNODB_SYS_FIELDS'
2014-09-22 23:33:06 2580 [Note] Shutting down plugin 'INNODB_SYS_COLUMNS'
2014-09-22 23:33:06 2580 [Note] Shutting down plugin 'INNODB_SYS_INDEXES'
2014-09-22 23:33:06 2580 [Note] Shutting down plugin 'INNODB_SYS_TABLESTATS'
2014-09-22 23:33:06 2580 [Note] Shutting down plugin 'INNODB_SYS_TABLES'
2014-09-22 23:33:06 2580 [Note] Shutting down plugin 'INNODB_FT_INDEX_TABLE'
2014-09-22 23:33:06 2580 [Note] Shutting down plugin 'INNODB_FT_INDEX_CACHE'
2014-09-22 23:33:06 2580 [Note] Shutting down plugin 'INNODB_FT_CONFIG'
2014-09-22 23:33:06 2580 [Note] Shutting down plugin 'INNODB_FT_BEING_DELETED'
2014-09-22 23:33:06 2580 [Note] Shutting down plugin 'INNODB_FT_DELETED'
2014-09-22 23:33:06 2580 [Note] Shutting down plugin 'INNODB_FT_DEFAULT_STOPWORD'
2014-09-22 23:33:06 2580 [Note] Shutting down plugin 'INNODB_METRICS'
2014-09-22 23:33:06 2580 [Note] Shutting down plugin 'INNODB_BUFFER_POOL_STATS'
2014-09-22 23:33:06 2580 [Note] Shutting down plugin 'INNODB_BUFFER_PAGE_LRU'
2014-09-22 23:33:06 2580 [Note] Shutting down plugin 'INNODB_BUFFER_PAGE'
2014-09-22 23:33:06 2580 [Note] Shutting down plugin 'INNODB_CMP_PER_INDEX_RESET'
2014-09-22 23:33:06 2580 [Note] Shutting down plugin 'INNODB_CMP_PER_INDEX'
2014-09-22 23:33:06 2580 [Note] Shutting down plugin 'INNODB_CMPMEM_RESET'
2014-09-22 23:33:06 2580 [Note] Shutting down plugin 'INNODB_CMPMEM'
2014-09-22 23:33:06 2580 [Note] Shutting down plugin 'INNODB_CMP_RESET'
2014-09-22 23:33:06 2580 [Note] Shutting down plugin 'INNODB_CMP'
2014-09-22 23:33:06 2580 [Note] Shutting down plugin 'INNODB_LOCK_WAITS'
2014-09-22 23:33:06 2580 [Note] Shutting down plugin 'INNODB_LOCKS'
2014-09-22 23:33:06 2580 [Note] Shutting down plugin 'INNODB_TRX'
2014-09-22 23:33:06 2580 [Note] Shutting down plugin 'BLACKHOLE'
2014-09-22 23:33:06 2580 [Note] Shutting down plugin 'ARCHIVE'
2014-09-22 23:33:06 2580 [Note] Shutting down plugin 'MRG_MYISAM'
2014-09-22 23:33:06 2580 [Note] Shutting down plugin 'MyISAM'
2014-09-22 23:33:07 2580 [Note] Shutting down plugin 'MEMORY'
2014-09-22 23:33:07 2580 [Note] Shutting down plugin 'CSV'
2014-09-22 23:33:07 2580 [Note] Shutting down plugin 'sha256_password'
2014-09-22 23:33:31 2580 [Note] Shutting down plugin 'mysql_old_password'
2014-09-22 23:33:31 2580 [Note] Shutting down plugin 'mysql_native_password'
2014-09-22 23:33:31 2580 [Note] Shutting down plugin 'binlog'
2014-09-22 23:33:31 2580 [Note] C:\Program Files\MySQL\MySQL Server 5.6\bin\mysqld.exe: Shutdown complete
```

Comment: [Pode ser o caso de criar manualmente o `my.ini`](http://stackoverflow.com/a/14598246/825789).

Comment: @bfavaretto, o erro sumiu, porém apareceu outro.

Comment: O erro ainda ocorre?

Comment: @Fernando, sim.

Comment: Então volte o my.ini original pois aparentemente, pela mensagem de can't connect, o MySQL não está nem rodando. Em seguida confirme como fazer para apenas adicionar no my.ini a diretiva necessária(explicit_defaults_for_timestamp)

Comment: Não havia `my.ini` original, eu tive que usar o método manual que o bfavaretto indicou, quanto as mensagens, elas apareciam desde antes da criação do `my.ini`.

Comment: A princípio coloquei apenas uma mensagem (a primeira) pois pensei que o problema estava ali somente, mas mais tarde percebi que não era esse o caso.

Comment: Tem ver isto com calma. A propósito, my.ini é em windows. My.cnf em linux.

Comment: Dá uma olhadela aqui: http://stackoverflow.com/a/16836525/1817673

Comment: Achou alguma solução? Poste como resposta para ajudar outras pessoas.

Comment: Ainda não achei nenhuma solução.

Answer (score 2):

Já passei por este problema e resolvi da seguinte maneira:

Editei o arquivo my.cnf (que no meu caso por ser em um servidor Debian linux, está armazenado em */etc/mysql/my.cnf*) e na tag `[mysqld]` inseri a seguinte definição:

```
explicit_defaults_for_timestamp = false
```

Desta forma a tag `[mysqld]` do meu arquivo my.cnf ficou da seguinte maneira:

```
[mysqld]
user            = mysql
pid-file        = /var/run/mysqld/mysqld.pid
socket          = /var/run/mysqld/mysqld.sock
port            = 3306
basedir         = /usr
datadir         = /var/lib/mysql
tmpdir          = /tmp
lc-messages-dir = /usr/share/mysql
explicit_defaults_for_timestamp = false
```

No seu caso, por ser Windows, creio que a diferença seria somente o local do arquivo de configuração do mysql, que provavelmente é o my.ini